# How to add new Metadata options (Date, Author, etc.) for Posts?

Tags: custom-field, post-meta, metabox

I would like to know if it's possible and how to create new Metadata options (like Date, Author, etc.) to show about a Post.

I tried using Advanced Custom Fields, but I can't seem to use the custom fields created as new Metadata options.

For example, I would like to create a new Metadata called Location, where i can put the desiderd location maybe linked to the dynamic custom field created with ACF.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is exactly what ACF does. What do you mean when you say you can’t use them as Metadata options? What are you calling “metadata options”?

Comment: For some reason, i don't have option to choose from ACF created fields, the button with the dynamic content, so i solved this by using Ele Custom Fields and creating a new Loop to show the information i needed.

Comment: What do you mean "option to choose from ACF created fields"? Option for what?